# cordova-plugin-esptouch doesn't work on Ios16

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

My App built in cordova phnegap uses cordova-plugin-esptouch plugin and it works fine on Ios versions lower than 16.0.

Here is what debbugger returns on ios 13 (or 14 or 15):

```
2023-02-06 21:27:05.014416+0100 test[2071:64929] ssid: Eki, bssid: 00:00:00:00:00:00, apPwd: eki123
2023-02-06 21:27:05.016094+0100 testn[2071:64929] Welcome Esptouch v0.3.7.0
2023-02-06 21:27:05.016216+0100 test[2071:64929] ESPTouchTask init
2023-02-06 21:27:05.017034+0100 test[2071:64929] ##########################client init() _sck_fd4=10
2023-02-06 21:27:05.017115+0100 test[2071:64929] ##########################client init() _sck_fd6=13
2023-02-06 21:27:05.017191+0100 test[2071:64929] ##########################server init(): _sck_fd4=14
2023-02-06 21:27:05.017318+0100 test[2071:64929] ##########################server init(): _sck_fd6=15
2023-02-06 21:27:05.017381+0100 test[2071:64929] ESPTouchTask app server port is 18266
2023-02-06 21:27:05.017454+0100 test[2071:64929] ESPTouchTask executeForResult() localInetAddr: 192.168.2.137
2023-02-06 21:27:05.018208+0100 test[2071:64929] ESPTouchTask __execute() send gc code
2023-02-06 21:27:05.018222+0100 test[2071:64930] ESPTouchTask beginBackgroundTask() entrance
2023-02-06 21:27:05.020075+0100 test[2071:64930] ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() start an asyn listen task, current thread is: <NSThread: 0x282bb6e00>{number = 5, name = (null)}
2023-02-06 21:27:05.020192+0100 test[2071:64930] ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() expectOneByte: 18
2023-02-06 21:27:11.026271+0100 test[2071:64929] ESPTouchTask __execute() send gc code
```

And this is what debbugger returns on ios 16:

```
2023-02-06 21:32:11.415065+0100 test[14030:3910256] ssid: Eki, bssid: 00:00:00:00:00:00, apPwd: eki123
2023-02-06 21:32:11.415841+0100 test[14030:3910256] Welcome Esptouch v0.3.7.0
2023-02-06 21:32:11.415941+0100 test[14030:3910256] ESPTouchTask init
2023-02-06 21:32:11.416769+0100 test[14030:3910256] ##########################client init() _sck_fd4=8
2023-02-06 21:32:11.416833+0100 test[14030:3910256] ##########################client init() _sck_fd6=9
2023-02-06 21:32:11.416938+0100 test[14030:3910256] ##########################server init(): _sck_fd4=10
2023-02-06 21:32:11.417042+0100 test[14030:3910256] ##########################server init(): _sck_fd6=11
2023-02-06 21:32:11.417099+0100 test[14030:3910256] ESPTouchTask app server port is 18266
2023-02-06 21:32:11.417156+0100 test[14030:3910256] ESPTouchTask executeForResult() localInetAddr: 192.168.2.109
2023-02-06 21:32:11.417755+0100 test[14030:3910256] ESPTouchTask __execute() send gc code
2023-02-06 21:32:11.417810+0100 test[14030:3910487] ESPTouchTask beginBackgroundTask() entrance
client: sendto fail, but just ignore it
: No route to host
2023-02-06 21:32:11.420914+0100 test[14030:3910487] ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() start an asyn listen task, current thread is: <NSThread: 0x2817e6300>{number = 8, name = (null)}
2023-02-06 21:32:11.421004+0100 test[14030:3910487] ESPTouchTask __listenAsyn() expectOneByte: 18
client: sendto fail, but just ignore it
: No route to host
client: sendto fail, but just ignore it
: No route to host
client: sendto fail, but just ignore it
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?
Thank you in advance.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall plugin, I also tried a new version cordova-plugin-esptouch 2.0, but nothing works.
I tested on ios 13, 14, 15 and 16 and only on version 16 it doesn't work.